# What is good/fast for performance ? AJAX Preload or load in click?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance

I have multiple ajax in a one web page and I also have modal that if clicked a data pop up that can be loaded using ajax.

I want to know if which is faster do I load it when the web page is loaded for first time or load it on click function?

Thanks for someone who will explain it or enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Performance based on how many time your `ajax` code take for each calls and amount of data transmitted.

As of mine you need to call `ajax` on click event.

*If you calls ajax on page load*,

- Calls many request and may someone not be used by user.
- Load on server.

*If you calls an ajax via button click*,

- Calls a single request.
- Prevent server load because we send a only one request at a time.

For more read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30069145/6656706).

Comment: If the button clicked again it will request the ajax again. Is that fine?

Comment: @Jovs you are right and isn't fine. For prevent second time calling you can add [Data Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp) and check it on second time [Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18775511/6656706).

Answer (score 0):

If the data is the same it shouldn't matter which method you choose. If you're worried about the website stuck on loading until the ajax call is done, show the user something else when it's still loading. This way the user will still see the website even when the ajax call is not done.

Comment: What do you mean I should show? When the website is loading I can't show anything yet. And my concern about on click function is inside the network that always request the data. Does that affect the performance ?

Comment: @Jovs You're still going to use the other ajax calls, correct? If the one for the click function will take longer than the others and you don't need it done on page load, then you don't need to change anything. Like the other guy said, it would be more of a backend issue since the different ajax calls will be finished independently of others so unless you're loading something very heavy all at once don't worry too much.